# Conflict between \MakeUppercase in title formatting and \usepackage{xcolor}

Tags: color, titlesec

I would like to make colored, upper case section titles. But somehow, the translation for all section items fails with:

```
 ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>

! Color stack action is missing. <to be read again>

! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `BLUE'.
```

I figured out that the conflict occurs when I am trying to combine the `\MakeUppercase` command in the `\titleformat` environment together with the `xcolor` package.

A MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}  %this line does not work
 %{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}                %works perfectly well

\begin{document}
\section{\color{blue} This is a blue, upper case section}
\end{document}
```

I work with Texmaker/MikTeX 2.9.
Any ideas how this issue can be solved?

Comment: Please, explain whether you want the same color for all sections or different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personnally try to avoid automatic `\MakeUpperCase`. It can have nasty side effects if the title contains special stuff like math oder commands. Also imho it doesn't look good, I prefer small caps.

Beside this: You shouldn't put the `\MakeUpperCase` in the format argument, but in the `before code`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}  

\begin{document}

\section{This is a blue, upper case section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! 
I also do not like upper case headings, however this was a specification for the paper I am working on.